# Evolution of animals' eyesight on habitable planets orbiting TRAPPIST-1?

Tags: biology, planets, evolution

Recently there have been up to two habitable planets discovered around the star TRAPPIST-1, if animal life was able to evolve on either planets how would eyesight evolve under such a dim star? How much different would it be compared to the eyesight of Earth animals?

More information about the star can be found by clicking on those links.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRAPPIST-1

http://www.trappist.one

Comment: I just asked a [question about animals in general](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/41144/28), though not about eyesight in particular -- I'm asking how far animal development could advance in that kind of environment.  (I'm not trying to compete; I think it's an independent question, something I was wondering about on the drive home tonight.)  Your question here seems to be mainly about eyesight, so I'd suggest dropping the photosynthesis part and asking a separate question about that.  How does that sound?  (The TRAPPIST-1 planets are exciting; plenty of questions there. :-) )

Answer (score 1):

I came up with three simple solutions that may help you here;

1. As the world is so dim it is possible that eyesight works similar to
   solar panels. The creatures that live there might be nocturnal,
   spending the day ''charging'' their eyes so that when they are
   awake, they can see.
2. They might also just see in a lower light frequency that doesn't require as much light or energy from their sun.
3. Finally the simplest, most boring answer ever; they see just like we do, but darker.

Comment: Hey, what would be The Sun's absolute magnitude from TRAPPIST-1?

Comment: @Stephanie pardon my English, but What?